# Visual Studio freezes when using ASP.NET/aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, master-pages, aspxgridview

I have a big problem when making a ASP.NET/aspx project in Visual Studio Ultimate. 
I have just started using website projects this week, so I don't have a lot of cache lying around.

1. It's VERY slow whenever I try to do ANYTHING.
2. Sometimes I can't even edit a label before it freeze for 20 seconds.
3. After a little time it freeze completly, and I can't do ANYTHING
4. It is worst to load items when it's fx GridView or greater items
5. I have NO problems doing 'normal' consol and WF projects
6. I have repaired and modifyed VS.
7. I have deleted the few cache files I had.
8. I have tried to restart my pc and vs, which helped for 10 min before it did the same again.

Anyone who know, whats wrong? My professor can't even help me, so I'm screewed to my exam if this doesn't get fixed

Comment: Have you completely uninstalled, then completely reinstalled VS (as opposed to a repair?) Are all service packs applied? What about reinstalling the .Net version that you are targeting? Usually the VS installer will take care of installing .Net for you; you may want reinstall .net and applicable sp's BEFORE running the installer for VS.

Comment: I seem to recall having an issue like this in Design View so badly I stopped using that view completely. If I remember right my particular issue was that I was missing a service pack for Visual Studio that corrected the lag issues. Where is the project you're connecting to? If it's over a network, you should try moving the files onto your machine and try editing it locally

Comment: I have tried to reinstall and the problem remains. I have tried just reinstalling .Net as well. No change. Kan you tell me, what 'sp' is?

The project I'm making is only online when I run it. But I will see if I can find the service pack. Which one is it?

Comment: I had a problem when I loaded visual studio which freeze and I resolved by deleting the .vs file in the project.